# Run Many ApplicationPools in one WebApplication on IIS 7+

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-applications, entity-framework-4, application-pool

It's possible to run more that one aplication pool in the same WebApplication on IIS 7 or 7.5? I have one web application on asp.net 4.0 that use EF 4.0 and a large set of Entities. Then the First query Its to slow and when the application pool fails, the users need to login again, but the pool was restarted and the first query Its too slow, this cause any can't login for a time (about the time that the old pool is finished and the new pool It's ready).

If I can use multiple applications pools for the same site, on the same port 8080 for example, thats solve my problem. The only way I found was to create a server farm. However, if I understand, each servers would be a virtual or real machine?

Comment: None of this sounds like a good idea

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple applications and associated pools running under one site directory root.  In IIS 7 manager, simply right-click on the folder in question and select "Create Application" in the resulting dialog set the new application pool and the physical path.  This will mean that you have to segregate your code into separate projects/modules (web applications or web application projects in vs) but they will all share the same site.